# Error in R-function when input is string

Tags: r, function, for-loop

I have made a function that tests which numbers in a range that are multiple of 6 and/or 3, or none of them.

```
Multi <- function(x,y) {
 z = x:y
 for (i in z) {
  if (i%%1!=0 | i<0) {
   print("Error!")
   break
 } else if (i%%3==0 & i%%6==0) { 
   print(paste(i, "is multiple of both 3 and 6"))
 } else if (i%%3==0) {
   print(paste(i, "is multiple of 3"))
 } else {
   print(paste(i, "is not multiple"))
  }
 }
}
```

The loop works as I want it to, but within the first if-statement, I would also like it to print `"Error!"` if a character/string is provided. The message I get when trying `Multi("Hello",10)` is:

`Error in x:y : NA/NaN argument
In addition: Warning message:
In Multi("Hello", 10) : NAs introduced by coercion`

I have tried the `suppressWarnings()` function, but I couldn't make it work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not use `is.numeric(c(x,y))` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Multi <- function(x,y) {
  if (!is.numeric(x) | !is.numeric(y)) {
    print("Error!")
  } else {
    z = x:y
    for (i in z) {
      if (i%%1!=0 | i<0) {
        print("Error!")
        break
      } else if (i%%3==0 & i%%6==0) { 
        print(paste(i, "is multiple of both 3 and 6"))
      } else if (i%%3==0) {
        print(paste(i, "is multiple of 3"))
      } else {
        print(paste(i, "is not multiple"))
      }
    }
  }
}
Multi(1,10)
Multi('Hello', 10) # now it will print Error without a NaN: 'Hello':10 was causing this NaN
```

You can reduce the code a little bit also

```
sapply(1:10, function(i) ifelse(i%%3==0, 
                                ifelse(i%%6==0, 
                                       paste(i, "is multiple of both 3 and 6"), 
                                       paste(i, "is multiple of 3")),
                                paste(i, "is not multiple")))
```